# Are there any wifi chipsets out there that don't have an internal uC or require Linux?

Tags: stm32, wifi

For the past few days I've been browsing wifi chipsets and their development tools. I noticed that all of them either require Linux for running (at least that's what the forums say) or have an internal microcontroller (usually a STM32F4 or something similar, only TI and Espressif use a different architecture).

I'd like to know if there are chipsets out there that can be driven from an external microcontroller (not via AT commands, I mean handle the lwip stack and send/receive packets to/from the chipset). Here's my situation, I need many hardware resources and I want wi-fi on my board (I'd like to be able to handle it), that's why I don't use an ESP8266, or a CYW43362 or a CC3200.

Is what I want possible or am I just dreaming? By the way I'm using a stm32 microcontroller.

PS: Maybe there is a modem out there that connects to an MII/RMII and then I can treat it as if it where regular ethernet? I found the nano wireach .. but it's just too expensive

Comment: Again, what is the problem with, say, ESP8266? How is it related to how much hardware resources you need?

Comment: If your wifi IC is smart then it needs to have a uc and run some firmware. If it's dumb then you need a software stack to the work, say encryption and the modem. If you want some wifi controller with MII/RMII interface, then you are simply asking a wifi AP minus the Ethernet PHY, which believes it or not usually has or internal uC and/or runs Linux.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I need 12 ADC channels, 2 UART, 2 SPIs and maybe ethernet.

Comment: So... how it is related to the wifi chip?

Comment: @EugeneSh. If maybe I could find a radio that deals withthe wireless part and accepts an external lwip to handle it, it would allow me to use a microcontroller that already has those features, and has a lwip port (imagine stm32)

Comment: Have you looked into using a wifi module?

Comment: Part of the reasons why they require Linux and not any other RTOS is they don't want to support them. The IC needs driver to function, the driver is written by vendor, and the vendor don't want anyone else to write another driver (by not providing the source code for their Linux driver or even the reference manual for their IC). And that's exactly what you want to do: to write drivers for the WIFI IC and integrate it into an existing TCP/IP stack. Unfortunately, WIFI and GPU are currently the most hostile to third-party development (including but not limited to open-source development).

Comment: I just stumbled upon this thread. I have exactly the same problem. I found that there are 4 modules which do not include a TCP stack but for which an RTOS driver exists (therefore can be used with lwIP or similar):
Atmel ATWILC1000 - (already mentioned), driver is to be found within the ASF
TI WL1801MOD - Driver documentation and download is convoluted, difficult to tell whether it is usable
Cypress CYW43362 - Driver is contained in the WICED IDE, only for some MCU's, including STM32
RTL8189 - Binary proprietary driver by Jorjin. Probably unusable. So, the ATWILC1000 is still best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - there is at least one - ATWILC1000 from Atmel. It is just a "dumb network interface". I've used it with my own MCU via SPI. LwIP runs on the MCU.

The module itself does have a small Cortus MCU that you have to load a ~170KB blob first, but otherwise you just use Atmel's (low-level) stack. There is LwIP reference code provided by Atmel.

Comment: Sorry it took me such a long time to answer ... apparently that's EXACTLY what I needed

Answer (score 5):

Well, what you want is self-contradicting.

Either, you get a relatively dumb WiFi interface that lets the operating system network stack handle the actual WiFi transmissions (and then you'll need some operating system that does that), or you'll need a system that integrates a controller that takes care of the WiFi handling. WiFi is a tad more complicated then let's say Ethernet.

Hence: You need complex logic *somewhere*.

Think about what you're about to do: You'll implement something that connects to a network. Something in that system will need to handle all the low-level timing and data layer stuff that WiFi requires. Something in that will also need to handle all the higher level (Ethernet frames, IP packets, maybe UDP or TCP packets, or even more high level above that, some kind of serial link emulated across that; not even to mention crypto and auth). So either you'll need to teach your STM32F4 how to do all that (which will actually be pretty hard) or you'll need some external controller that does that for you and e.g. gives you a simple serial interface.

Even when buying WiFi cards for PCs, you'll notice that these contain extensive firmware themselves. You just can't get around the fact that you need something timing-wise close to the radio to handle all the low-level stuff.

**TL;DR:** either your WiFi IC needs to be smart, or you need a smart OS. Most of the time, both. You can't have the cake and eat it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I know from AT commands tells me that I don't have much control over the packets, and implementing something a little more complex like a captive portal via AT commands is not possible. I was hoping that maybe there was a processor out there that is capable of handling the wifi and let lwip handle the packets.

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you seem to be looking for, even though it is not quite clear: you want to use your *own* TCP/IP stack that will be implemented (using lwip) on your MCU, rather than the stack provided by the Wifi module.

It seems there are, indeed, a few Wifi module that can be connected to your microcontroller through some MII interface (usually RMII, actually), so it acts "a bit" like an ethernet PHY.

For example, this one: [Nano WiReach](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/84/Nano_WiReach_DS-1_13-190627.pdf) (Note: this specific product is obsolete). You can clearly see on page 3-1 of the datasheet that it can be used as you suggested (directly connected to your MCU EMAC through RMII).

**But**: It is not just a "Wifi PHY". It can't be, since the PHY layer for wifi does not have the same timings/requirements as ethernet 10/100 (see [Transparent Wi-Fi module with RMII input](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/225915/transparent-wi-fi-module-with-rmii-input)). So it actually acts as a **bridge**. And, if you look in the details, you'll see this module actually embeds a rather powerful MCU with a complete firmware able to understand even much higher-level protocols, if you want it to (HTTP, FTP, telnet, ...). And it also has other interfaces through which you can connect your microcontroller (SPI, UART).

So, I didn't look at the module's manual, but I'm pretty sure that this module, although it provides a RMII interface, still requires SPI or UART (AT commands?) to be used for, at least, configuring the module to act as a bridge between RMII and Wifi. Then, you can send your packets.

But anyway, *all* wifi modules embed their own MCU and usually, their own TCP/IP stack.

However, there are some standard modules to which you can also send raw packets through SPI or other, and use your own MCU's TCP/IP stack. In fact, even the ESP8266 seems to be able to do that: see this [project](https://gitlab.com/goodwin-europe/raw-esp).